Azure API Management Portal Returning Invalid Secrets in React Custom Widget
I'm encountering an issue with my custom React widget in the Azure API Management portal. The widget uses an unmodified secrets hook to retrieve values from the managed portion of the portal through a postMessage() method. Historically, I received the expected management API URL from the managementApiUrl attribute, but recently, this has changed, leading to issues.
Previously, the managementApiUrl attribute returned a value similar to:
{
  "parentLocation": { … },
  "managementApiUrl": "https://<redacted>.developer.azure-api.net/developer",
  "apiVersion": "2022-04-01-preview",
  "token": "SharedAccessSignature token=\"<redacted>", refresh=\"true\"",
  "userId": "1"
}

However, now the managementApiUrl attribute returns a URL in the format:
https://<redacted>.management.azure-api.net/subscriptions/000/resourceGroups/000/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/<redacted>

This change is causing my widget to fail when trying to interact with the management API. I haven't made any changes to the widget or the secrets hook.
Questions:
Has anyone experienced similar issues with Azure API Management?
Is there a recent change or update in the Azure API Management service that could cause this behavior?
How can I revert to or configure the portal to return the previous format of managementApiUrl?
I've tried creating new widgets, trying different Azure API-M instances, validating the config.json endpoint, and event calling config.json to pull that information direct (can't because of CORS).
I expect to see the actual management API URL but instead get the "developer" endpoint of the managed portal.

It seems you’re encountering an issue with your custom React widget in the Azure API Management portal. Specifically, the managementApiUrl attribute is returning a different format than expected.
The URL format is:
https://apim-instance.management.azure-api.net/subscriptions/{yoursubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{yourresourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{yourserviceName}/apis?api-version=2021-08-01


I referred to the Azure API Management REST API Authentication documentation to generate a SAS key and authenticate to the Azure API Management with REST API.

The React code below is for fetching and displaying Azure API Management data for Groups and APIs:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';

const apiVersion = '2014-02-14-preview';
const serviceName = 'AzureAPIManagementServiceName';
const baseUrl = `https://${serviceName}.management.azure-api.net`;
const sharekey = 'uid=${identifier}&ex=${expiry}&sn=${signature}';

function App() {
  const [groups, setGroups] = useState([]);
  const [apis, setApis] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const groupsResponse = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/groups?api-version=${apiVersion}`, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `SharedAccessSignature ${sharekey}`,
          },
        });
        setGroups(groupsResponse.data.value);

        const apisResponse = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/apis?api-version=${apiVersion}`, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `SharedAccessSignature ${sharekey}`,
          },
        });
        setApis(apisResponse.data.value);
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err.message);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const formatJSON = (json) => {
    return JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(json), null, 2);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Azure API Management</h1>
      {error && <p>Error: {error}</p>}
      <div>
        <h2>Groups</h2>
        {groups.length > 0 ? (
          groups.map((group, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <h3>Group {index}</h3>
              <p>id: {group.id}</p>
              <p>name: {group.name}</p>
              <p>description: {group.description}</p>
              <p>builtIn: {group.builtIn.toString()}</p>
              <p>type: {group.type}</p>
              <p>externalId: {group.externalId}</p>
              <hr />
            </div>
          ))
        ) : (
          <p>No groups found</p>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>APIs</h2>
        {apis.length > 0 ? (
          apis.map((api, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <h3>API {api.id}</h3>
              <pre>{formatJSON(JSON.stringify(api))}</pre>
              <hr />
            </div>
          ))
        ) : (
          <p>No APIs found</p>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


Outputs of Groups:

Output of APIs:


For more details refer REST API documentation for Azure API Management.


I appreciate the response but you aren't addressing the question. I'm not interested in hardcoding the management API URL in my custom widget.
To clarify, I start with the custom widget template provided by Microsoft. Then use the unmodified useSecrets and useRequest hooks. useSecrets fetches the secrets object from the managed portal window which contains the managementApiUrl attribute. At a minimum I expect that value to be https://{serviceName}.management.azure-api.net but occasionally it is in the form https://{serviceName}.developer.azure-api.net or completely empty.

@rylan-michael I have give a sample example url  https://${serviceName}.management.azure-api.net  with  sas key/sas token  from this  doc use above example and  modify it to useSecrets and useRequest hooks.
